# Deep link always comes null. OS Android. Facebook

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0

I did everything according to the documentation, but I always get an empty answer

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.1.1'
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.3"
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$compose_version"

    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:13.0.0'
}
```

My manifest looks like this

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.GameTopMoney"
        tools:targetApi="31">


        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.GameTopMoney">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="posture"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Id String
`<string name="facebook_app_id">820734572369738</string>`

And MianActivity

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val gameViewModel: GameViewModel by viewModels<GameViewModel>()

        FacebookSdk.setIsDebugEnabled(true);
        FacebookSdk.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.APP_EVENTS);

        setAutoInitEnabled(true)
        fullyInitialize()
        AppLinkData.fetchDeferredAppLinkData(
            this
        ) {
            println("Deeplink  >>>>------->  " + it)
        }
    }
```

In console I get the following info from sdk facebook

```
D/FacebookSDK.com.facebook.appevents.AppEventQueue: Flush completed
    Params: {"event":"CUSTOM_APP_EVENTS","anon_id":"XZf0a2d3f8-7b3d-4aad-8a45-bc8f061288ee","application_tracking_enabled":true,"advertiser_id_collection_enabled":true,"advertiser_id":"7fa85bca-a20e-46d0-8261-3187189d3883","advertiser_tracking_enabled":true,"extinfo":"[\"a2\",\"com.moddev.gametopmoney\",1,\"1.0\",\"12\",\"sdk_gphone64_x86_64\",\"en_US\",\"GMT\",\"T-Mobile\",1440,2928,\"3.5\",4,6,4,\"GMT\"]","application_package_name":"com.moddev.gametopmoney"}
      Result: Success
      Events JSON: [
      {
        "_eventName": "fb_mobile_deactivate_app",
        "_eventName_md5": "92255b491a4e25b5d809edcf3665affe",
        "_logTime": "1669498427",
        "_ui": "MainActivity",
        "_session_id": "bd209590-b213-4f93-a524-f2d93716e69e",
        "fb_mobile_time_between_sessions": "session_quanta_19",
        "fb_mobile_launch_source": "Unclassified",
        "fb_mobile_app_interruptions": "3",
        "_valueToSum": 231.054
      },
      {
        "_eventName": "fb_mobile_activate_app",
        "_eventName_md5": "cb7f3b6cd294afce05ece615d43ea7b9",
        "_logTime": 1669538829,
        "_ui": "MainActivity",
        "_session_id": "bd209590-b213-4f93-a524-f2d93716e69e",
        "fb_mobile_launch_source": "Unclassified",
        "fb_mobile_pckg_fp": "fe92a46e9431b173997aff454dc93f41",
        "fb_mobile_app_cert_hash": "Pgk9lXoPktAPy3MKEetZWMa61vs=\n"
      }
    ]
```

Application setup in facebook console
[image: link img 1]
[image: link img 2]
[image: link img 3]
[image: link img 4]

**I send a request using the "App Advertising Assistant" service**

link com.moddev.gametopmoney://123

[image: link img 5]
[image: link img 6]

I receive a notification from facebook on the emulator

[image: link img 7]

I click on it and open my app. In response, I see null in the console

```
2022-11-27 12:16:16.257 7697-7736/com.moddev.gametopmoney D/com.facebook.FacebookSdk: getGraphApiVersion: v13.0
2022-11-27 12:16:16.258 7697-7736/com.moddev.gametopmoney I/System.out: Deeplink  >>>>------->  null
2022-11-27 12:16:16.482 7697-7736/com.moddev.gametopmoney D/com.facebook.FacebookSdk: getGraphApiVersion: v13.0
```

I can't figure out why I'm getting null in the response. I tried to create two app in facebook account and still getting null